# How to represent or use NAN in double operations?

Tags: visual-c++

In visual studio 2019, NAN is defined in corecrt_math.h (folder Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt) as follows:

`#define NAN        ((float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))`

Yes, it is a float number, not double. How to get a representation in double? For instance, if it is assigned to a double variable,
`double x = NAN`, I get the warning:

"C26451: Arithmetic overflow. Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2)."

Note: The code and algorithm is not mine, I just want to remove the warning in the best way

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan

Comment: @HansPassant, Thank you. In this way, I just found a ```quiet_NaN()``` in <limits> header. It is defined as follows: 
```_NODISCARD static constexpr double quiet_NaN() noexcept { return __builtin_nan("0"); }```
But it is a function, not a 'ready' value.

Comment: Why is that a problem? In what way does `double x = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();` fail to meet your requirements?